# Creating a project from a folder in IntelliJ Idea 12

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a code in Java. It contains only *.java files in the nested directories and nothing else. I want to create a java project using it. How do I do that in IntelliJ Idea 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Import Project**, select the directory with the existing sources (or its parent that you want to be the project root), follow the wizard steps.

More details can be found in [online help](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/import-project-or-module-wizard.html).